# SQL query, How can I find the pair of friends who have the most common friends?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.
users table:

```
USERS(ID,NAME)
```

Friend relationships:

```
FRIEND(ID1,ID2)
```

and I want to find the pairs of users that have the most shared friends while the two users are not friends.

Finally, I want to print the pair of names of the two users.
An example is like:

Users table:

```
(1,Jimmy)
(2,Sam)
(3,Alices)
(4,Tom)
```

Friend table:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(4,2)
(4,3)
```

As users 1 and 4 have mutual friends 2,3. Users 2 and 3 have mutual friends 1,4. The both two pairs of friends have the number of shared friends 2. So we want to print their names as the results:

```
Jimmy,Tom
Sam,Alices
```

How can I do this in one query?

Comment: _most shared friends while they are not friends_ I don't understand this. Who are not friends? Could you clarify this and maybe add some sample input/output data?

Comment: @jpw I think the OP is after people having the most mutual friends, however they personally are not friends with each other.

Comment: Have a look at this link : http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=72097

Comment: @jpw, I have clarify it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SQL Server to test it, because I have only SQL Server at hand, but it should be straight forward to convert it to Oracle syntax.

I've converted it to Oracle using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48e1f/21/0), though I've never seen Oracle before. See the final query at the bottom.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @USERS TABLE (ID int, NAME nvarchar(255));

DECLARE @FRIEND TABLE (ID1 int, ID2 int);

INSERT INTO @USERS (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'Jimmy');
INSERT INTO @USERS (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'Sam');
INSERT INTO @USERS (ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO @USERS (ID, NAME) VALUES (4, 'Tom');

INSERT INTO @FRIEND (ID1, ID2) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO @FRIEND (ID1, ID2) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO @FRIEND (ID1, ID2) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO @FRIEND (ID1, ID2) VALUES (4,3);
```

**Pairs of users**

We need pairs of users. This is done by `CROSS JOIN`. `CROSS JOIN` would return twice as many rows as we need `(1,2) and (2,1)`, but we need only one of those, so we'll add a filter by user `ID`.

```
WITH
CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT
        U1.ID AS ID1
        ,U2.ID AS ID2
    FROM
        @USERS AS U1
        CROSS JOIN @USERS AS U2
    WHERE
        U1.ID > U2.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Pairs;
```

Result set:

```
ID1    ID2
2      1
3      1
4      1
3      2
4      2
4      3
```

**Pairs that are not friends**

Once we have all pairs we should remove those pairs that are friends already. The table `FRIEND` can list a pair as `(1,2)` or as `(2,1)`, so we should check both possibilities. We'll use `EXCEPT` to "subtract" these rows.

```
....
,CTE_PairsNonFriends
AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM CTE_Pairs

    EXCEPT

    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM @FRIEND

    EXCEPT

    SELECT ID2, ID1
    FROM @FRIEND
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_PairsNonFriends;
```

Result set:

```
ID1    ID2
3      2
4      1
```

**Friends of selected users**

We have a final list of pairs. For each user we need to get a list of his immediate friends. Simple `join` is enough. Again table `friend` can have `(1,2)` or `(2,1)`, so we need to do it twice. And we do it for user `ID1` first, then separately for user `ID2`.

```
....
,CTE_FriendsOfUser1
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1 AS IDUser1
        ,F1.ID2 AS FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1

    UNION -- sic! not ALL

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1 AS IDUser1
        ,F1.ID1 AS FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1
)
,CTE_FriendsOfUser2
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2 AS IDUser2
        ,F1.ID2 AS FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2

    UNION -- sic! not ALL

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2 AS IDUser2
        ,F1.ID1 AS FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2
)
```

Result set:

```
SELECT * FROM CTE_FriendsOfUser1

IDUser1    FriendOfUser1
4          2
4          3
3          1
3          4


SELECT * FROM CTE_FriendsOfUser2

IDUser2    FriendOfUser2
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          4
```

**Mutual friends**

`join` user1 with user2 on their list of friends to find their common friends.

```
....
,CTE_MutualFriends
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1
        INNER JOIN CTE_FriendsOfUser2 ON CTE_FriendsOfUser2.FriendOfUser2 = CTE_FriendsOfUser1.FriendOfUser1
    WHERE
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1.IDUser1 <> CTE_FriendsOfUser2.IDUser2
)
```

**Count mutual friends**

```
,CTE_FriendCount
AS
(
    SELECT
        IDUser1
        ,IDUser2
        ,COUNT(*) AS FriendCount
    FROM CTE_MutualFriends
    GROUP BY IDUser1, IDUser2
)
```

**Final full query with user names**

Order results by the friend count. You can return only first row (or first few rows) to return users with the most number of mutual friends. Actually, it should by `TOP` with ties.

```
WITH
CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT
        U1.ID AS ID1
        ,U2.ID AS ID2
    FROM
        @USERS AS U1
        CROSS JOIN @USERS AS U2
    WHERE
        U1.ID > U2.ID
)
,CTE_PairsNonFriends
AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM CTE_Pairs

    EXCEPT

    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM @FRIEND

    EXCEPT

    SELECT ID2, ID1
    FROM @FRIEND
)
,CTE_FriendsOfUser1
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1 AS IDUser1
        ,F1.ID2 AS FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1

    UNION -- sic! not ALL

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1 AS IDUser1
        ,F1.ID1 AS FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1
)
,CTE_FriendsOfUser2
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2 AS IDUser2
        ,F1.ID2 AS FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2

    UNION -- sic! not ALL

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2 AS IDUser2
        ,F1.ID1 AS FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN @FRIEND AS F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2
)
,CTE_MutualFriendsRaw
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1.FriendOfUser1 AS MutualFriend
        ,IDUser1
        ,IDUser2
    FROM
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1
        INNER JOIN CTE_FriendsOfUser2 ON CTE_FriendsOfUser2.FriendOfUser2 = CTE_FriendsOfUser1.FriendOfUser1
    WHERE
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1.IDUser1 <> CTE_FriendsOfUser2.IDUser2
)
,CTE_MutualFriends
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MutualFriend
        ,CASE WHEN IDUser1 < IDUser2 THEN IDUser1 ELSE IDUser2 END AS IDUser1
        ,CASE WHEN IDUser1 < IDUser2 THEN IDUser2 ELSE IDUser1 END AS IDUser2
    FROM
        CTE_MutualFriendsRaw
)
,CTE_FriendCount
AS
(
    SELECT
        IDUser1
        ,IDUser2
        ,COUNT(*) AS FriendCount
    FROM CTE_MutualFriends
    GROUP BY IDUser1, IDUser2
)
SELECT
    CTE_FriendCount.IDUser1
    ,CTE_FriendCount.IDUser2
    ,CTE_FriendCount.FriendCount
    ,U1.NAME AS Name1
    ,U2.NAME AS Name2
FROM
    CTE_FriendCount
    INNER JOIN @USERS AS U1 ON U1.ID = CTE_FriendCount.IDUser1
    INNER JOIN @USERS AS U2 ON U2.ID = CTE_FriendCount.IDUser2
ORDER BY FriendCount DESC
;
```

Result set:

```
IDUser1    IDUser2    FriendCount    Name1    Name2
4          1          2              Tom      Jimmy
3          2          2              Alice    Sam
```

There may be a problem with `CTE_MutualFriends`. Again the same problem that a pair can be listed as `(1,2)` or `(2,1)`. You can have, say, pair `(a,b)` with count `NN` and a pair `(b,a)` with another count `MM`. Strictly speaking there should be another step that looks for such pairs and combines them together. I'm not sure if with the current query such pairs are possible or not.

There **is** a problem with original version of `CTE_MutualFriends`, so I've added extra step to eliminate duplicates in the final full version of the query. The given sample data is too small and simple to have all possible variants, so the version version was giving correct results. If we add more entries in the sample data we'll see that extra step is needed.

**Oracle syntax version**

Checked with  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48e1f/21/0

```
WITH
CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT
        U1.ID  ID1
        ,U2.ID  ID2
    FROM
        USERS  U1
        CROSS JOIN USERS  U2
    WHERE
        U1.ID > U2.ID
)
,CTE_PairsNonFriends
AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM CTE_Pairs

    MINUS

    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM FRIEND

    MINUS

    SELECT ID2, ID1
    FROM FRIEND
)
,CTE_FriendsOfUser1
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1 IDUser1
        ,F1.ID2 FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN FRIEND F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1

    UNION

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1  IDUser1
        ,F1.ID1  FriendOfUser1
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN FRIEND  F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID1
)
,CTE_FriendsOfUser2
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2  IDUser2
        ,F1.ID2  FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN FRIEND  F1 ON F1.ID1 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2

    UNION 

    SELECT
        CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2  IDUser2
        ,F1.ID1  FriendOfUser2
    FROM
        CTE_PairsNonFriends
        INNER JOIN FRIEND  F1 ON F1.ID2 = CTE_PairsNonFriends.ID2
)
,CTE_MutualFriendsRaw
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1.FriendOfUser1  MutualFriend
        ,IDUser1
        ,IDUser2
    FROM
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1
        INNER JOIN CTE_FriendsOfUser2 ON CTE_FriendsOfUser2.FriendOfUser2 = CTE_FriendsOfUser1.FriendOfUser1
    WHERE
        CTE_FriendsOfUser1.IDUser1 <> CTE_FriendsOfUser2.IDUser2
)
,CTE_MutualFriends
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MutualFriend
        ,CASE WHEN IDUser1 < IDUser2 THEN IDUser1 ELSE IDUser2 END  IDUser1
        ,CASE WHEN IDUser1 < IDUser2 THEN IDUser2 ELSE IDUser1 END  IDUser2
    FROM
        CTE_MutualFriendsRaw
)
,CTE_FriendCount
AS
(
    SELECT
        IDUser1
        ,IDUser2
        ,COUNT(*) FriendCount
    FROM CTE_MutualFriends
    GROUP BY IDUser1, IDUser2
)
SELECT
    CTE_FriendCount.IDUser1
    ,CTE_FriendCount.IDUser2
    ,CTE_FriendCount.FriendCount
    ,U1.NAME  Name1
    ,U2.NAME  Name2
FROM
    CTE_FriendCount
    INNER JOIN USERS  U1 ON U1.ID = CTE_FriendCount.IDUser1
    INNER JOIN USERS  U2 ON U2.ID = CTE_FriendCount.IDUser2
ORDER BY FriendCount DESC
;
```

Comment: FYI, you can use SQL Fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) to test in other DBMSs.

Comment: @DavidFaber, I used sql fiddle to convert the query to Oracle syntax. As I expected it was pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
WITH uf AS (
    SELECT id1 AS user_id, id2 AS friend_id FROM friends
     UNION ALL
    SELECT id2 AS user_id, id1 AS friend_id FROM friends
), xf AS (
    SELECT user_id1, user_id2, friend_cnt FROM (
        SELECT uf1.user_id AS user_id1, uf2.user_id AS user_id2
             , COUNT(*) AS friend_cnt
             , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
          FROM uf uf1 INNER JOIN uf uf2
            ON uf1.friend_id = uf2.friend_id
           AND uf1.user_id < uf2.user_id
         GROUP BY uf1.user_id, uf2.user_id
    ) WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT xf.friend_cnt, u1.username || ',' || u2.username
  FROM xf INNER JOIN users u1
    ON xf.user_id1 = u1.user_id
 INNER JOIN users u2
    ON xf.user_id2 = u2.user_id;
```

In the first CTE I am getting users with their friends; in the second I am getting users with friends in common, then ranking them by count; in the main query I am just getting the usernames and concatenating them.

[**Please see SQL Fiddle demo here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24a42/3) Notice that even though Jimmy and Tom each have four friends in the demo, the value of `friend_cnt` is 3 as that is the number of friends they have in common (I added a few friends to your sample data).